# Saving angular form data - spring boot Jackson error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jackson

please any angular developper expert ? I'm stuck nd here's my issue : 
I'm working on an app : frontend/Angular Backend/springBoot
Ihave a form with select inputs that get data from database through spring boot controllers til now that's fine ! but whene i try to save the form data it generates error 500 on angular and this error on spring boot :

```
WARN 10200 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4956b52a; line: 1, column: 226] (through reference chain: ma.munisys.entities.CtrctCustomer["project_name"])
```

here's my angular code :

**entity class :**

```
import {Customer} from "./model.customer";
import {CtrctCustomerProduct} from "./model.contratClientProduit";
import {CtrctSupplier} from "./model.contratFournisseur";

export class CtrctCustomer {

  id:any;
  dteStrt:Date;
  dteEnd:Date;
  ctrtName:string;
  customer:Customer;
  project_name:string;
  pilote:string;

  ctrctCustomerProducts:Array<CtrctCustomerProduct>=new Array();

  contrats:Array<CtrctSupplier> = new Array();

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

**here's my html code :**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveContrat()">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label for="contracts">Nom contrat :</label>
                   <ng-select id="contracts" [items]="contractName"
                   bindLabel="name"
                   name="contracts"
                   [typeahead]="contractNameTypeahead"
                   placeholder="Selectionner un contrat"
                   typeToSearchText="Saisir un contrat"
                   [(ngModel)]="contrat.ctrtName">
           </ng-select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label for="codeProjet">Code Projet :</label>
            <ng-select id="projects" [items]="contractName"
                       bindLabel="id"
                       name="id"
                       [typeahead]="contractNameTypeahead"
                       placeholder="Selectionner un projet"
                       [addTag]="addTag"
                       addTagText="Référence"
                       notFoundText="Aucun projet trouvé"
                       typeToSearchText="Saisir un code projet"
                       [(ngModel)]="contrat.project_name"
                       required></ng-select>
          </div>
```

and here's the part where i recuparate data from database through web service ive created :

```
this.contractNameTypeahead.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(200),
      term => this.renouvellementService.getAllContratClient()
    ).subscribe(res => {
          this.contracts = res; 
          console.log(res[0]['ctrtName']);   

          this.contractName = this.contracts.map((contracts) => {
            console.log(contracts);
            return { name: contracts.ctrtName, id: contracts.project_name };

           });
      });

  onSaveContrat() {

    this.contrat.ctrctCustomerProducts.forEach(
      p => {
        if (p.product.distributeur.ref != null){
          console.log(" ref not null");
            p.product.distributeur.id=null;
            p.product.distributeur.name = p.product.distributeur.ref;
            p.qteDisponible = p.qte;
            p.devise = 'MAD';
        }

      }
    );

    this.renouvellementService.**saveContratClient(this.contrat)**.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.mode = 2;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

this methode is what call the web service on the backend :

```
 **saveContratClient(ctrctCustomer:CtrctCustomer)** {
    return this.http.post(this.host+'/save-contrat-client', ctrctCustomer,{headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': this.authentificationService.getToken()})});
  }
```

Comment: Can we see the `onSaveContrat()` method, and any methods it calls please?

Comment: onSaveContrat() {

    this.contrat.ctrctCustomerProducts.forEach(
      p => {
        if (p.product.distributeur.ref != null){
          console.log(" ref not null");
            p.product.distributeur.id=null;
            p.product.distributeur.name = p.product.distributeur.ref;
            p.qteDisponible = p.qte;
            p.devise = 'MAD';
        }

      }
    );

    this.renouvellementService.saveContratClient(this.contrat).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.mode = 2;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
 )}

Comment: Please add it to the question as an edit. Code is unreadable in SO comments…

Comment: done ! can you please check ?

Comment: If you're certain your server accepts JSON POST requests, try adding a `'Content-type': 'application/json'` header to your request.

Comment: how can i be sure that my server accepts it ?

Comment: If you can, ask whoever wrote it :-) if not, there should be documentation somewhere as to how it expects requests to look. Have you tried adding the the header?

Comment: Yes , the error presists and my server accepts json post too

Comment: Then it looks to me like you have a Spring Boot problem rather than an Angular problem. On the Angular side everything looks good to me.

Comment: Error is from backend, share your class in which you map all the fields.

Comment: I'm working with spring boot so im using jpa method save to save the fields there's no special code nd jpa does all the work

Comment: Please, post your spring controller code too.